# selection not reflecting in select input with ngOptions

Tags: angularjs

Angular is not able to reflect selected option in select input. Below is my complete code. `Hospital One` should have been selected, but not happening, what could be the reason ?

I've also put the same code snippet in  [JsBin](https://jsbin.com/pohowu/edit?html,js,output)  also.

```js
angular.module('testApp', [
  
])

.controller('AppController', function(){
  
  var vm = this;
  
  //
  vm.schedule = {
    date : "2015-5-25", 
    organization : {
      "_id":"55df26cf756549c15b5fbcd2",
      "name":"Hospital One",
      "kind":"HOSPITAL",
      "email":"somehospital1@hospital.com"
    }
  };
  
  //
  vm.user = { 
    name : "Some user name",
    affiliates : [
    {
        "_id":"55df26ea756549c15b5fbcd5",
        "createdOn":"2015-08-27T15:04:10.376Z",
        "organization":{
            "_id":"55df26cf756549c15b5fbcd2",
            "kind":"HOSPITAL",
            "name":"Hospital One",
            "email":"somehospital1@hospital.com"
            
        }
    },
    {
        "_id":"55df26ea756549c15b5fbcd4",
        "createdOn":"2015-08-27T15:04:10.375Z",
        "organization":{
            "_id":"55dbfd280713a3aa0d85158a",
            "kind":"CLINIC",
            "name":"Some Clinic",
            "email":"someclinic@clinic.com"
            
        }
    }
]
  };
  
})

;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="testApp">
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body ng-controller="AppController as vm">
    <h3>Selected Is : </h3>
    <pre>{{ vm.schedule.organization | json }}</pre>
    
    <h3>But selection is not reflecting in select</h3>
    <select ng-model="vm.schedule.organization" ng-options="affiliate.organization as affiliate.organization.name for affiliate in vm.user.affiliates | orderBy : 'organization.name' track by affiliate.organization._id">
      <option value="">-- Choose Organization --</option>
    </select>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is a typo. `<select ng-model="vm.shcedule.organization"` should be `<select ng-model="vm.schedule.organization"`. Check if the typo is also in your code or only on your post here.

Comment: Thanks for finding, fixed, but still not working

Comment: When I run your snippet it is working for me in Chrome v45

Comment: Check the below solution, please
https://jsbin.com/duxigigadu/1/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [ngOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) docs:

> select as and track by:
>
> Do not use select as and track by in the same expression. They are not
>   designed to work together.

Just remove the 'track by' and it'll work fine.

```
<select ng-model="vm.schedule.organization" ng-options="affiliate.organization as affiliate.organization.name for affiliate in vm.user.affiliates | orderBy : 'organization.name'">
```

[working bin](https://jsbin.com/xopoqaxago/1/edit?html,js,output)

-----EDIT------

Your options and your selected value are two different objects at first, therefore you'll always see the `<-- Choose Organization -->`  option as selected before changing the select.

In order to solve that you need to bind the selected to be one of the options.

here's a [working bin](https://jsbin.com/fenejivega/1/edit?html,js,output) that solves that issue as well

Comment: Thanks for useful information but still not working.

Comment: Check edit please, is that the issue you were referring to as "not working"?

Comment: Thanks again buddy, I am facing the same problem as mentioned in ngOptions documentation, But I can't do what you are doing in JsBin as it is the response from the server, but I got clue to move forward, really appreciated your effort and your time. Thanks.

Comment: Sure thing mate, and if i understand you correctly, it should be just the same with a response from the server (promise), just initialize the selected after it's resolved.